# Rest API response not updating until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, gatsby

I've got component that displays contact information from a dealer as chosen by a user. To be more specific, a user selects their location, setting a cookie which then is used to define the API call. I pull in the contact information of the dealer in that location using Axios, store it in a context, and then display the information as necessary through several components: the header, a "current location" component etc.

The problem that I'm currently running into is that the contact information, as displayed in the `Header` for example, doesn't update until a user performs a hard refresh of the page, so, assuming the default text of the button is something like "Find A Dealer", once a dealer is selected, the button label should say the name of the dealer the user has selected. At present, it isn't working that way. Below is the code for the `Header` component, and my `ApiContext`.

**ApiContext.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';
import { makeUseAxios } from 'axios-hooks';
import { useCookie } from 'hooks/use-cookie';

const contextObject = {} as any;

export const context = createContext(contextObject);

const useAxios = makeUseAxios({
  axios: axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.GATSBY_API_ENDPOINT }),
});

export const ApiContext = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [cookie] = useCookie('one-day-location', '1');
  const [{ data }] = useAxios(`${cookie}`);

  const { Provider } = context;
  return <Provider value={data}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

**Header.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Logo from 'assets/svg/logo.svg';
import css from 'classnames';
import { Button } from 'components/button/Button';
import { Link } from 'components/link/Link';
import { MenuIcon } from 'components/menu-icon/MenuIcon';
import { context } from 'contexts/ApiContext';

import { NotificationBar } from '../notification-bar/NotificationBar';
import s from './Header.scss';
import { MainNav } from './navigation/MainNav';

interface HeaderProps {
  navigationContent: ReactNode;
}

export const Header = ({ navigationContent }: HeaderProps) => {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const data = useContext(context);
  
  const buttonLabel = data ? data.name : 'Find a Dealer';
  const buttonLink = data ? `tel:${data.phone}` : '/find-a-dealer';

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const isScrolled = window.scrollY > 10;
      if (isScrolled !== scrolled) {
        setScrolled(!scrolled);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [scrolled]);

  return (
    <>
      <NotificationBar notificationContent={navigationContent} />
      <header className={scrolled ? css(s.header, s.header__scrolled) : s.header}>
        <nav className={s.header__navigation}>
          <ul className={s.header__container}>
            <li className={s.header__logo}>
              <Link to="/" className={s.header__link}>
                <Logo />
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className={s.header__primary}>
              <MainNav navigationItems={navigationContent} />
            </li>

            <li className={s.header__utility}>
              <Button href={buttonLink}>{buttonLabel}</Button>
            </li>

            <li className={s.header__icon}>
              <MenuIcon onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a screenshot of my console logs, where I'm logging what is returned from `data` in the `ApiContext`.

[image: console.log(data)]

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated, even if it means completely refactoring the way that I'm using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I was able to figure this out myself.

Using the recommendations from Ferran as a base, I decided that it would be best to rehydrate the components displaying the contact info from a state, but as I'm using this context in multiple components, I needed to have the state update globally. I moved away from `makeUseAxios`, to a traditional `axios` call. The dealer ID is then stored in the state and used in the call. I also created the `changeDealer` const, which I can pass through the context, and which updates the state:

`ApiContext.tsx`

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

const contextObject = {} as any;

export const context = createContext(contextObject);

export const ApiContext = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [dealerId, setDealerId] = useState(`1`);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${process.env.GATSBY_API_ENDPOINT}/${dealerId}`).then((res) => setDealerId(res.data));
  }, [dealerId]);

  const changeDealer = (value: any) => {
    setDealerId(value);
  };

  const { Provider } = context;
  return <Provider value={{ data: dealerId, changeDealer: changeDealer }}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

Then if, for example, I have a button that updates the dealer info, I import the context to the component and pass `changeDealer` through the it:

```
import { context } from 'contexts/ApiContext';
const { changeDealer } = useContext(context);
```

I can then attach it to a button like so:

```
<Link to="/" onClick={() => changeDealer(dealer.id)}>
  Set Location
</Link>
```

This updates the state globally, changing the contact information across all the components that display it. I will be storing the data in a `localStorage` item, allowing the data to persist after a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, your `ApiContext` looks good, it retrieves the information and populates the context, however, what you are missing is a `useState` to trigger an update to force the re-hydration of your buttons.

What is happening is that your context never updates the `data` constant. At the first rendering is empty, once your request is done and the `context` is full but your button is never being updated. Something like this may work for you:

```
  const data = useContext(context);
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState(data);
    
  const buttonLabel = newData? newData.name : 'Find a Dealer';
  const buttonLink = newData? `tel:${newData.phone}` : '/find-a-dealer';
```

You may need to adapt the code a bit to fit your requirements, nevertheless, you may keep the idea, which is creating a state with your retrieved data.

You can create a `useEffect` to control when the data changes and populate the state if you wish:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setNewData(data)
}, [data])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great start! Integrating this, along with the `useEffect`, I'm still only seeing the buttons update on a page refresh. Anyplace else you could steer me?

Comment: Could you debug by placing `console.logs`/`debugger` to check how is re-hydrating your code?

Comment: What part in particular?

Comment: I want to check out if `data` is populated properly

Comment: Question has been updated with a screenshot! Thank you!

Comment: I can also provide you a link to the staging site, which has the current changes if that would be easier.

Comment: Is this component reaching your state in your header?

Comment: So, I've managed to work something out, I'm just trying to get a few details taken care of to make sure it works. Essentially, I set the ID for the API call in a state, but the state is contained in the `ApiContext`. I'm also building a function that I can pass through the context to buttons etc. so that we can change the ID on a button click, but it will update the state globally.